# OpenGL ES 2.0 on android phones without GPU?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Will a game run faster using OpenGL ES 2.0 on a Android device without GPU than using the Canvas? Or since it will run on CPU anyway there wont be any big differences in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can run OpenGL ES 2.0 on an Android device without GPU. And if you could, performance would be abysmal —you'd be lucky to move a Pong-like game @ 10 FPS—. Emulating vertex and pixel programs on software is several orders of magnitude slower than running them on a GPU.

Comment: That makes sense... So should I create a rendered that can render the game using Canvas or OpenGL and check if the device has a GPU?

Comment: Which phones are you trying to account for?

Comment: Note that OpenGL ES 2.0 support is now mandatory with latest versions of Android.